# Extjs4 MVC, how get Model or View from a Controller class?

Tags: extjs, view, model, extjs4

```
Ext.define('DigitalPaper.controller.Documents', {
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

 views:  ['Documents'],
 stores: ['Documents'],
 models: ['Documents'],

 init: function() {
     console.log('[OK] Init Controller: Documents');
 } 
});
```

What's the function to get Model or View of this controller?
I've tried

```
  Ext.getModel('Documents');
  this.getModel('Documents');
  this.getModel();
  this.getDocumentsModel();
```

Any suggests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution Found:

In the Controller it is possible to use the reference to the View:

```
refs: [{
    ref: 'viewDocuments', // will be create the method this.getViewDocuments();
    selector: 'Documents'
}],
```

So you can get the View with this:

```
this.getViewDocuments();
```

Comment: Nobody ever seems to say where the "this.getViewDocuments();" needs to be - or what "this" is in the context people are expecting me to use it :(

Comment: @PaulHutchinson By utilizing the 'refs' section of the ExtJS controller definition, you can create quick references to commonly accessed components. References automagically create 'getter' methods based on the provided text for 'ref'. In this example, the created getter is 'getViewDocuments'. This can be called throughout the controller, where 'this' refers to the controller scope. The 'selector' definition is used in the resulting Ext.ComponentQuery.query() call. See the docs for ComponentQuery.query() and see how powerful the selector definition can be!

Answer (score 7):

Ext controllers are pretty weird, in that there is a single instance of a given controller, no matter how many related view instances you might have. In most MVC or MVP systems there is one controller instance per view instance.

If you plan to use multiple view instances, then you should not keep references to those views in the controller.

You might want to look into Deft's MVC extension for ExtJs that has one controller instance per view instance (plus dependency injection):

http://deftjs.org/

Anyways, controller.getView() returns a reference to the view CLASS, not an object instance. Same with getModel(). getStore() DOES return a store instance.

In your controller, you can do something like this:

```
this.viewInstance = this.getDocumentsView().create();
```

I would also recommend naming your model in the singular. It is not a Documents. It is a Document.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Ext.define('DigitalPaper.controller.Documents', {
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

 views:  ['Documents'],
 stores: ['Documents'],
 models: ['Documents'],

 init: function() {
     console.log('[OK] Init Controller: Documents');

     // get references to view and model classes which can be used to create new instances
     console.log('View', this.getDocumentsView());
     console.log('Model', this.getDocumentsModel());

     // reference the Documents store
     console.log('Store', this.getDocumentsStore());

 }
```

});

These methods are created by a method in the Ext controller that creates the getters.
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Controller.html#Ext-app-Controller

Here is what that method looks like:

```
createGetters: function(type, refs) {
    type = Ext.String.capitalize(type);
    Ext.Array.each(refs, function(ref) {
        var fn = 'get',
            parts = ref.split('.');

        // Handle namespaced class names. E.g. feed.Add becomes getFeedAddView etc.
        Ext.Array.each(parts, function(part) {
            fn += Ext.String.capitalize(part);
        });
        fn += type;

        if (!this[fn]) {
            this[fn] = Ext.Function.pass(this['get' + type], [ref], this);
        }
        // Execute it right away
        this[fn](ref);
    },
    this);
},
```

Comment: getDocumentsView() does not return an instance of a Documents view

Comment: Good point. I updated the example snippet with comments that note what the getters are returning.

Comment: View function() Model function() Store Object { events={...}, data={...}, groupers={...}, altri elementi...} -> I get this in console, it works for the store but it doesn't for View and Model. I get "function()"

Answer (score 0):

getModel() and getView() do not return the model / views of the controller - they return instances of these in the app (and if none exist, they will be instanced).

You can simply use this to get the view / model names:

```
this.views[0]
```

I'm not sure where you are using your gets ( ie, this.getModel('Details') ), but these should  correctly return an instance of the model (the constructor is the only place you might have issues referring to these).

Comment: This answer does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes, I must have misunderstood the question. And you are right, getModel returns the class not an instance; that's why we use .create();